# call answer from a previous function

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function in R that will return as its output, an one output from a previous function. The previous function returns a list of 3 different things.

So far the only way I've worked out how to do this is completely copy and paste the original function, and get it to return only one answer, but surely there is a shorter way in which to do this?

Comment: You should post the code you have problems with (or better a stripped down version still containing the problem).

Comment: I have a function: return(list(residuals, residualssquared,tss))

and i want to write a function that returns only tss, without having to have the body of the previous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original function is named `foo()`, as in

```
foo <- function ( something ) {
  # some code
  return(list(residuals, residualssquared,tss))
}
```

then just do

```
bar <- function ( something ) {
  return ( foo(something)$tss )
}
```

or simply use `foo(something)$tss` to directly access the `tss` component of the return value of `foo()`. There is really no need to wrap another function `bar()` around `foo()`.